# parsing json with java

Tags: java, json, json-lib

I am a newbie to json parsing, I have grabbed a json string from a request and now I need to parse it with java. I'm using json-lib for this. But I'm really stuck as I'm not familiar with it. I need to extract following data

```
1. name (hotel name)
2. starRating
3. geoPoint
```

I used following java code for that but it's not giving me the result I need, please someone help me...

Thanks a lot!

java code (s is the json string I get)

```
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(s);    
JSONArray jarray = json.getJSONArray("hotels");
for(int i=0 ; i < jarray.size(); i++) {
System.out.println("jarray [" + i + "] --------" + jarray.getString(i));
}
```

json I need to parse

```
[
{
    "total": 250,
    "offset": 0,
    "requestID": "-btygi09oxfov",
    "locationName": "Paris, France",
    "locationLatitude": 48.86,
    "locationLongitude": 2.34,
    "cityCode": "PARIS_J_FR",
    "hotels": [
        {
            "ypid": "YN10001x300073304",
            "id": 56263,
            "hotelRateIndicator": "2",
            "name": "Renaissance Paris Vendome Hotel",
            "brandCode": "69",
            "addressLine1": "4 Rue du Mont-Thabor",
            "city": "Paris",
            "neighborhood": "",
            "state": "IdF",
            "country": "US",
            "cachedPrice": 935,
            "geoPoint": [
                48.865361,
                2.329584
            ],
            "starRating": "5",
            "thumbnailUrl": "http://www.orbitz.com//public/hotelthumbnails/53/97/85397/85397_TBNL_1246535840051.jpg",
            "total": 250,
            "amenities": [
                "24",
                "31",
                "42",
                "52",
                "9"
            ],
            "telephoneNumbers": [
                ""
            ],
            "popularity": 837
        },
        {
            "ypid": "YN10001x300073331",
            "id": 112341,
            "hotelRateIndicator": "3",
            "name": "Renaissance Paris Arc de Triomphe Hotel",
            "brandCode": "69",
            "addressLine1": "39 Avenue de Wagram",
            "city": "Paris",
            "neighborhood": "",
            "state": "IdF",
            "country": "US",
            "cachedPrice": 633,
            "geoPoint": [
                48.877107,
                2.297451
            ],
            "starRating": "5",
            "thumbnailUrl": "http://www.orbitz.com//public/hotelthumbnails/21/72/302172/302172_TBNL_1246535872514.jpg",
            "total": 250,
            "amenities": [
                "24",
                "31",
                "42",
                "9"
            ],
            "telephoneNumbers": [
                ""
            ],
            "popularity": 796
        }           
  ]         
}           
  ]
```

Comment: What's not working? Are you getting an error? Or not getting the data you require?

Comment: @adrin : I get an exception Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: net.sf.json.JSONArray cannot be cast to net.sf.json.JSONObject

Answer (score 6):

Any JSON object can be represented as a `Map<String, Object>`.

Use a library like [jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) (shipped with spring), which can deserialize json to a Map like this:

```
Map<String, Object> obj = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>());
```

Or the [slower](https://github.com/fabienrenaud/java-json-benchmark), but google-branded, [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), which can be used like.

```
Map<String, Object> obj = new Gson().fromJson(json, HashMap.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'm in a situation where I must use json-lib :)

Comment: Gee - 2 downvotes? Honestly, gson can build java objects from json and visa versa so easily. Anyway...

Comment: I just did a benchmark of some of the most popular json libraries in java. I was shocked when i saw GSON is the least performing modern library (there are older and worse ones). Take a look for yourself if you don't believe me: https://github.com/fabienrenaud/java-json-benchmark
I always assumed jackson and gson were similar in performance before... jackson is a clear winner in this pic tho.

Comment: @fab that's good, because long since I posted this answer I have been using jackson, not because it's faster, but because it comes out of the box with spring boot, which I have been using a lot in recent years. I've updated the answer to include jackson and a link to your benchmark.

Answer (score 5):

To get past the ClassCastException, you just need to make the change it's telling you to make: to handle the input as an array and not as an object.

```
JSONArray outerArray = (JSONArray) JSONSerializer.toJSON(s);
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) outerArray.get(0);
JSONArray jarray = json.getJSONArray("hotels");
for (int i = 0; i < jarray.size(); i++)
{
  System.out.println("jarray [" + i + "] --------" + jarray.getString(i));
}
```

And, here's an example of getting each hotel name.

```
JSONArray outerArray = (JSONArray) JSONSerializer.toJSON(s);
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) outerArray.get(0);
JSONArray jarray = json.getJSONArray("hotels");
for (int i = 0; i < jarray.size(); i++)
{
  JSONObject hotel = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
  String name = hotel.getString("name");
  System.out.println(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Djson parser(java library). 
https://github.com/jungkoo/djson_parser

code:

```
Var hotels = Djson.parse(new File("d:\\sample1.txt")).find("[0].hotels");

for(int i=0; i<hotels.size(); i++) {            
  System.out.println(hotels.get(i).get("name").toString());
  System.out.println(hotels.get(i).get("starRating").toInt());
  System.out.println(hotels.get(i).find("geoPoint").get(0).toDouble()); // case1) basic
  System.out.println(hotels.get(i).find("geoPoint[1]").toDouble()); // case2) find()    
  System.out.println();
}
```

output:

```
Renaissance Paris Vendome Hotel 5
48.865361
2.329584

Renaissance Paris Arc de Triomphe Hotel 5
48.877107
2.297451
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the [**`json-lib`**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/json-lib/files/json-lib/json-lib-2.2.2/) and Use [**`JSONObject`**](http://www.json.org/java/)

Lets say  `{"name": "joe", "age": 33}`

Do like this

```
JSONObject jobject=new JSONObject(jsonstring);
String name=jobject.getString("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have started a github project project called JsonQuery that makes this kind of thing easier.

The project is built on top of GSON.

If you wanted to retrieve the name of your hotel, for example, it could be as simple as this:

```
JsonQuery $ = JsonQuery.fromJson(s); 
$.val("hotels.name");
```

Here is the link:

https://github.com/rdbeach/JsonQuery